# Mongodump not stored in the specific location

Tags: mongodb

I am doing a `mongodump`, and want to store it in a specific location. So, from reading online, I can do this using the following command:

```
sudo mongodump -d mydbs -u user -p password -o /myfolder/mongoBackups
```

I am using an EC2 instance, and when I run this command from my centos home folder, this is the output I get from mongodump:

```
2017-01-07T16:01:42.053+0000    writing mydbs.users to 
2017-01-07T16:01:42.055+0000    done dumping mydbs.users (2 documents)
```

However, when I cannot find the folder `myfolder/mongoBackups` anywhere in the specific `home/centos` location where I run it. Any idea why?

Comment: you are using **absolute path**. try `ls -l /myfolder/mongoBackups`

Comment: what does absolute path mean? When I do the above I can see the folder, but why cant I see it otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

It's not within `home/centos`

It's in `/myfolder/mongoBackups`

Specifying an output directory of `/myfolder/mongoBackups` is basically putting it in a folder called myfolder on the root of the hard drive.

If you truly want the folder to be within `home/centos` try

```
sudo mongodump -d mydbs -u user -p password -o /home/centos/myfolder/mongoBackups
```